# Parent Select SQL Query generating Child Select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

These are my tables:

**Table_Bill_Summary**

`| Date | PersonId | BillNo |`

**Table_Bill_Items**

`| BillNo | ItemId | Quantity |`

**Item_MasterTable**

`| ItemId | ItemName | ItemRate |`

I am going to specify a PersonId. This is what I want to print:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Bill_Summary
WHERE PersonId=@X
    (SELECT IM.ItemName,BI.Quantity,IM.ItemRate
     FROM Table_Bill_Items AS BI
     INNER JOIN Item_MasterTable AS IM ON BI.ItemId=IM.ItemId
     WHERE BI.BillNo=??)
```

My result should look like:

```
23/04/2013      Person123       Bill32
    Item20  23  100
    Item21  20  200
    Item23  1   300
23/04/2013      Person123       Bill39
    Item2   2   100
    Item11  40  800
    Item43  1   700
```

I want a child `Select` Query to be run for each row retrieved by the parent `Select` query on the column `BillNo`

Comment: What language is your application developed using?

Comment: @eggyal I'm using C# and ASP.NET and I'm using iTextSharp to print this on a PDF.

Comment: @divinediu I think we could use Rdlc instead of itextsharp that will be quite simple for this scenario.we can directly give data source on table.

Comment: @RajaRajendraprasath I'm using iTextSharp for printing in all my other software. I need to stick to that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select FLD1,FLD2,FLD3 from
(
SELECT CAST(Date as varchar(10)) as FLD1  ,CAST(PersonId as varchar(10)) as FLD2,
cast(BillNo as varchar(10)) as FLD3,1 as FLD4, Billno as fld5
FROM Table_Bill_Summary WHERE  PersonId =@X

union

SELECT CAST(IM.ItemName as varchar(10)) as FLD1  ,CAST(BI.Quantity as varchar(10)) as FLD2,CAST(IM.ItemRate as varchar(10)) as FLD3 ,2 as FLD4, BS.Billno as fld5
FROM Table_Bill_Summary BS inner join Table_Bill_Items AS BI  on bs.BillNo=BI.BillNo
INNER JOIN Item_MasterTable AS IM  ON BI.ItemId=IM.ItemId
WHERE  Bs.PersonId =@X
) as x order by fld5,fld4
```

Comment: Good answer. You could have elaborated your technique a little, though ;-) You should use UNION ALL here, as there will be no duplicates which is what UNION is looking for to eleminate.

Comment: @Auto Raja Prakash yes i think this will work. i have checked by creating locally.Small correction that i have made on your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in SQL.  Instead, perform the operation in your application by fetching the joined results (bills and items) sorted by bill and keeping track of the last seen bill when iterating through the resultset:

```cs
string stm = @"
  SELECT   BillNo, Date, ItemName, Quantity, ItemRate
  FROM     Table_Bill_Summary
      JOIN Table_Bill_Items USING (BillNo)
      JOIN Item_MasterTable USING (ItemId)
  WHERE    PersonId = @Person
  ORDER BY BillNo
";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Person", person_id);
MySQLDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

bool isMore = rdr.Read();
while (isMore) {
  int current_bill = rdr.GetInt32(0);
  // output bill
  do {
    // output item
  } while (isMore = rdr.Read() && rdr.GetInt32(0) == current_bill);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. (At least not without some queer tricks ;-) An SQL select statement will always result in a list of rows showing the *same* columns.

You would usually solve this with a reporting software or with another programming language and GUI.

Comment: I'm using asp.net and c#. Can you please guide me or link me to a solution to my problem?

Comment: No, not directly. However, one way would be to run the main select statement and fill an array with the results. Then record for record, you put the data in a grid control (or treeview control), then execute your dependent SQL and fill the child data with ist result. The other way is to write an SQL statement holding all main and detail values joined. Then you loop through the result list and on every group change detected you'd write a header line in your control.

Comment: Ah, you just got an answer from Anto Raja Prakash showing the queer trick ;-) You equalize column types to be able to union them. This can get rather clumsy with large select statements, but is a possibility to solve this by SQL only.